# Uniswap V2's swapExactETHForTokens: How to know the number of tokens bought

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I wrote the solidity function below to swap ether for other tokens on a Uniswap exchange. It works.

```
function buyCryptoOnUniswap1(uint256 etherCost , address cryptoToken) public payable returns (uint256) {

  IUniswapV2Router02 usi = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
      
   if(etherCost > address(this).balance){
          return 0;
    }
    uint deadline = now + 300; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    
    uint[] memory amounts = usi.swapExactETHForTokens.value(etherCost)(0, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);
    uint256 outputTokenCount = uint256(amounts[1]);
    
    return outputTokenCount;
      }


  function getPathForETHToToken(address crypto) private view returns (address[] memory) {
       
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = usi.WETH();
    path[1] = crypto;
    
    return path;
  }
```

According to the docs, the returned value called **`amounts`** is an array of `uints` which consists of the input token amount and all subsequent output token amounts.

*`amounts,  uint[] memory,  The input token amount and all subsequent output token amounts.`*

So I hazarded a guess as to it(the number of purchased tokens) been in index 1 of the return value.

**Please how do I get the number of tokens returned by this transaction?**

Sorry, but it doesn't seem so clear from the documentation..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obviously the amount of the last token in the path, i.e., `amounts[amounts.length - 1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be sure, so that I would not be surprised in production. Thanks again